# Print Bool matrix but replace true and false with 1's and 0's

Tags: arrays, boolean, ocaml

I'm doing a task where I need to have a function  `printmat : bool array array -> unit = <fun>`  that
given a bool matrix it prints it on screen with ones and zeros, instead of
true and false.

So far, I only managed to print the already existing matrix with 1's and 0's and my first variable is a string instead of bool. I was just wondering how to change to code so I need to CALL the function and type in the bool array array instead of having the declared one?

```
let matrix = [|
 [|true; true; false; false|];
 [|false; false; true; true|];
 [|true; false; true; false|];
 [|true; false; false; true|]
|];;

let print_s matrix =
 let n = Array.length matrix in
 for i = 0 to n - 1 do 
   let n1 = Array.length matrix in
   for j = 0 to n1 - 1 do
     print_string matrix.(i).(j);
   done; 
   print_string "/n";
 done;;
```

Answer (score 3):

You code already has a function, `print_s`, which you have to call something like this,

```
let example = [|
  [|"1"; "0"|];
  [|"0"; "1" |]
|]

print_s example;;
```

It will print something like

```
10/n01/n-
```

This indicates that your function has three problems:

1. no separation between row elements
2. missing new line (should be `"\n"` not `"/n"`)
3. wrong input type, you want `bool array array` but it accepts `string array array`

To print a boolean value as a number, you can write a helper function and use it instead of `print_string` (which obviously accepts a string). You can use `if/then/else` to distinguish between two possible states of a bool variable. So if the boolean value is true, then you should print `"1"` else you should print `"0"`.